# Similar Codes, Different Effect

Tags: css

I am a beginner in designer, I had to develop a small website, where i designed a ui, but i have problems regarding css.

Here's a style i have written

```
background-image: url("../images/border_bottom_left.png"), url("../images/border_bottom_right.png"), url("../images/border_top_left.png"), url("../images/border_top_right.png");
background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top left, top right;
background-color:grey;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

which inserts four images to four corners and fills all the other part with a grey background

Now, instead of grey, i wanted to insert an image, So i replaced `background-color` with `background-image: url("../images/bg_content.png")` but it does not help me. I tried to use the `bg_content.png` in the first `background-image` and write its corresponding position to `center`, it didn't work?

Can anyone of you please help me!

Comment: That was a blunder on typing the question, It's now edited

Comment: What happened when you put the image in your `background-image` and set it to center?  Seems like that should work.  Did you try `center center` or just `center`?

Comment: @JamesMontagne , that puts the new image in center, without repeating, or stretching it, that should be the work of `background-repeat` on the next line.

Comment: @cipher okay, you didn't mention you wanted it to repeat.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add the image to your `background-image` and your `background-position`, then expand your `background-repeat`:

```
background-image: url("../images/border_bottom_left.png"), url("../images/border_bottom_right.png"), url("../images/border_top_left.png"), url("../images/border_top_right.png"), url("../images/bg_content.png");
background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top left, top right, top left;
background-color:grey;
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5k8eg/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But someone else wrote that before you. :) ... and it works (never mind)

Comment: @cipher It's not always about the quickest answer. Sometimes it's about the best answer. This answer is certainly more complete.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok +1. See the [fastest gun in the west problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Answer (score 1):

`background-color` cannot specify a url, only a color. You will need to use more than one `div` (or whatever element you are using) to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: You cant have two images in your `background-image` rule either. Actually, I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because your background image doesn't get repeated (as do the corner images) therefore, it will get covered up by one of the corner pictures. Try to set the first background-image to repeat:

```
background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know `background-color` doesn't accept image files. Try `background-color:#4B4C4D` instead. For picking up HTML colors you can use [this online color picker](http://www.colorpicker.com/).

**EDIT**: place a `div` inside another `div` and give those `div`s different `background-image` values. One div can have only one background image.

However in CSS3 you can have more than one background images. Visit [this link](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) for that purpose.

Comment: CSS3 lets you have multiple background images for a div.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you specified center for X and Y of the 5th image ?

```
background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top left, top right, center center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YhZ8e/